# How do I combine Git repositories?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-history-graph, .git-info-grafts

I am trying to combine 2 repositories into 1, by grafting the history. I would assume this is the easiest way to obtain a clean linear history.

I tried do so by adding the other as a remote to an initial repository:

```
git init    
echo "Hello" > Hello.txt
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add b c:\pathToB
git replace --graft master b/master
```

The tree looks fine, the problem is that I don't get the contents of repo B in the current directory.

I've also tried this (the commit hash is the tip of b/master)

```
git filter-branch -f --parent-filter 'sed "s~^\$~-p b34fc98295273c41aeb203213ad5fe4f95ba205b~"'
```

As I inspect the tree I can see that each commit contains it's changes, but the first commit in the main repo is basically removing all the changes brought in by repo B:

[image: repos]

None of the original commits are deleting files.

What am I missing, am I using filter-branch and grafts wrong? Or do I just have to use cherry-pick or rebase in order to keep all the changes in the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You need to combine the trees.  For instance, you could use `git merge`.  If your Git is new enough you will need the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag.  Such a merge will use an empty tree as the merge base, so that it thinks that the change from merge base to *L* is "add all files in commit *L*" and the change from merge base to *R* is "add all files in commit *R*" (where *L* and *R* are defined the way I like to define them for `git merge`; see, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710392/1256452)).

#### Long

Commits are snapshots.  (This part, I hope, is not controversial.)

Git's `git replace` objects are, quite literally, *replacements*.  That is, whenever Git is about to look up an object by its hash ID `1234567...` (or whatever), Git first checks: *Is there a replacement listed for `1234567...` in `refs/replace/`?*  If there is such a replacement, Git reads out the replacement object, by resolving `refs/replace/1234567...` to a *different* hash ID, and reading that object.

So:

> ```
> git init    
> echo "Hello" > Hello.txt
> git add -A
> git commit -m "initial commit"
> ```

This sequence first creates a new, completely empty repository (assuming there is no Git repository yet so that `git init` does the creating).  The `echo` command creates a file in the work-tree; `git add -A` adds the work-tree file to the index (which has the side effect of storing the file's data into the repository as a *blob* object, although that's not critical here).  The last step, `git commit ...`, creates a *tree* object to hold the snapshot—which has one file in it, `Hello.txt`, with the content you put in it—then creates a commit object such as `1234567...` that lists you as the author and committer, has the message "initial commit", uses the tree created to hold the snapshot, and—because it's the first commit ever—has no parent commits: it's a new root commit.

Now we have:

> ```
> git remote add b c:\pathToB
> ```

This simply adds the URL (and `fetch` setting) for the new remote `b`.

There is a step missing:

```
git fetch b
```

which calls up another Git (on your local machine since `c:\pathToB` is local—usually we'd call up a Git on another machine, over HTTPS or SSH or some such, but this is fine) and downloads objects from it.  Specifically, it gets any commits they have that you don't (which is all of their commits) and any objects that are needed to complete those commits (which are all of their other objects) and copies them into your repository.  These all have some ID that is *not* `1234567...`, since each commit has a guaranteed-unique hash ID.

Finally:

> ```
> git replace --graft master b/master
> ```

This tells your Git to set up one of those replacements.  In particular, it says that it should copy the commit identified by `master`—which we've said above is `1234567...`—to a new commit that's *just like* the original, except that it has a *parent* hash which is whatever commit `b/master` identifies.  Let's say that `b/master` identifies commit `fedcba9...`.

Let's say that the new commit that `git replace` commits has ID `8888888...`.  Its contents are:

- you as author and committer, copied from `1234567...` or created anew (this doesn't really matter);
- the date stamp copied from `1234567...` or created anew (this doesn't really matter either);
- the message copied from `1234567...`;
- ***the tree (snapshot) copied from `1234567...`*** (this part is critical); and
- a parent hash of `fedcba9...`.

Your existing `master` still identifies `1234567...`, but now when you ask Git to *show* you `1234567...`, your Git sees that `refs/replace/1234567...` exists and says "don't use that one, use `8888888...` instead".  So your Git looks up object `8888888...` and finds the tree you saved with `1234567...`, which has just the one file in it.  The commit *before* this one—the replacement substituting in for `1234567...`—has different files, so the change from then to now must be: delete all those files, and create `Hello.txt` instead.

To make your *next* saved snapshot use *both* trees in some way, you need to combine the tree for your `master` with the tree for `b/master`.  That's never going to be `git replace` (although whether it's `git merge` or something different/fancier is up to you).

Comment: Thank you for writing down this answer, it's what I suspected was happening. What about filter-branch, that is supposed to walk the tree and rewrite all the commits, shouldn't that be able to do a rebase-like merge? If grafts cannot bring over the changes, then what are they good for?

Comment: It's true that filter-branch copies each commit, applying filters; but you must supply the filters. The filter you'd want would have to do all the tree-merging, which is the hard part. Grafts are good for splicing in a bit of artificial history, which is sometimes a decent way to set things up before the "copy all commits" pass of filter-branch, after which you toss the original commits in favor of the new copied commits which makes the replacement (graft) permanent (in the new copies).